# more efficent shell text manipulation

Tags: linux, bash

I am using this command:

cut -d: -f2

To sort and reedit text, Is there a more efficient way to do this without using sed or awk?

I would also like to know how I would append a period to the end of each field

At the moment the output is like $x['s'] and I would like it to be $x['s'] .

Just using standard unix tools

edit: I just wanted to know if it was possible without sed or awk, otherwise how would you do it with awk?

Comment: I can't see the difference between $x['s'] and $x['s']...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** not really

**Longer answer:** `cut` is intended for slicing up lines of text, it does that well. If you need a more complicated behavior, you'll  need a text manipulation language. You have rejected the old time answers, so I'll recommend `perl`.

---

Any particular reason you don't want to use `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: I'll add Python as an alternative, and mark this as a helpful answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I choose perl for two reasons: 1) I might be able to write a script without opening a book, and 2) I was miffed by the slight to awk. ::sniff::holds back tears:: There is certainly no reason you couldn't use tcl, ruby, guile...

Answer (score 0):

> edit: I just wanted to know if it was possible without sed or awk, otherwise how would you do it with awk?

awk -F: '{print $2"."}'